# Group Rows Based On Column Value And Keep Row With Minimum Value In R

Tags: r, dataframe

In the data set below, I want to first check which rows for the column `U` and `D` have same value. Then, for such set of rows having `U` and `V` as same value, I want to keep that row which has minimum value for columns `Mean`, `Min` and `Max`. For the data I have, these three will always have minimum values for the same row out of the group of rows where `U` and `V` match.

I tried `group()` function, but it hasn't yielded in output as I want. Please suggest any efficient approach.

**Input Data**

```
data <- structure(list(A = c(0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 
0.18, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), B = c(0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 
0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4), C = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Yes", class = "factor"), 
    U = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ABC-001", "PQR-001"), class = "factor"), 
    D = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ABC", "PQR"), class = "factor"), 
    E = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), 
    F = c(22000014L, 22000031L, 22000033L, 22000025L, 22000028L, 
    22000020L, 22000021L, 22000015L, 11100076L, 11200076L, 11100077L, 
    11200077L, 11100078L, 11200078L), G = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, 0.2, 0.2), H = c(100, 100, 
    100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 0.9, 0.9
    ), I = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("us", "V"), class = "factor"), 
    Mean = c(38.72, 37.52111111, 38.44166667, 39.23666667, 39.35888889, 
    38.96, 38.95333333, 38.41777778, 0.691707061, 0.691554561, 
    0.691516833, 0.691423506, 0.763736, 0.764015761), Min = c(34.05, 
    33.25, 33.31, 35.14, 33.91, 33.78, 33.78, 33.75, 0.6911166, 
    0.6908743, 0.6908813, 0.6907286, 0.7609318, 0.7616949), Max = c(43.83, 
    42.12, 43.57, 44.03, 44.88, 44.03, 44.02, 43.52, 0.692533, 
    0.6922278, 0.6923681, 0.6919283, 0.7674736, 0.7668633)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

**Expected Ouput**

```
output <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "    A   B   C   U   D   E   F   G   H   I   Mean    Min Max
+ 0.18  0.33    Yes ABC-001 ABC B   22000031    0   100 us  37.52111111 33.25   42.12
+ NA    2   Yes PQR-001 PQR B   11200077    -0.1    1.2 V   0.691423506 0.6907286   0.6919283
+ ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check with `order` and `duplicated` all from base `R`

```
data = data[order(data$Mean),]
output = data[!duplicated(data[c("U","D")]),]
output
      A    B   C       U   D E        F    G     H  I       Mean        Min        Max
12   NA 2.00 Yes PQR-001 PQR B 11200077 -0.1   1.2  V  0.6914235  0.6907286  0.6919283
2  0.18 0.33 Yes ABC-001 ABC B 22000031  0.0 100.0 us 37.5211111 33.2500000 42.1200000
```

---

If you want `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(U, D) %>% slice(which.min(Mean))
```

Comment: .@Wen-Ben - Thank you. How do I ensure that the row order is same as that of the original data by considering `U` being the unique key between two data sets?

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil you can order with rowname  then the order of new df will be the same like df=df[order(rownames(df)),]

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this would be with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(U, D) %>% filter(Mean == min(Mean))
```

The output looks like this

```
      A     B C     U       D     E            F     G     H I       Mean    Min    Max
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <fct>   <fct> <fct>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1  0.18  0.33 Yes   ABC-001 ABC   B     22000031   0   100   us    37.5   33.2   42.1  
2 NA     2    Yes   PQR-001 PQR   B     11200077  -0.1   1.2 V      0.691  0.691  0.692
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider aggregating then joining back to original data. Below `names()` is used to re-order columns and `merge` omits `by` since all columns in aggregate resultset will be matched:

```
agg_df <- aggregate(cbind(Mean, Min, Max) ~ U + D, data, FUN=min)

merge(data, agg_df)[names(data)]
#      A    B   C       U   D E        F    G     H  I       Mean        Min        Max
# 1 0.18 0.33 Yes ABC-001 ABC B 22000031  0.0 100.0 us 37.5211111 33.2500000 42.1200000
# 2   NA 2.00 Yes PQR-001 PQR B 11200077 -0.1   1.2  V  0.6914235  0.6907286  0.6919283
```